# Good pointers to learn foundations of Program induction and Program synthesis

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, programming-languages, artificial-intelligence, program-synthesis

I was interested in learning more about program induction and program synthesis. I was especially interested in learning about how to form program from data for example. My background is in traditional ML+Neural Nets so I have no idea were to start...I am familiar with Program Sythesis by Sketching but beyond that don't know what would be a good say, introduction textbook to the field. Any pointers to get started would be good! Especially if they are the standard foundations for program synthesis/induction.

Of course I saw there are wikipedia articles but they didn't seem like a great reference to learn the foundations and then move forward...

Comment: One approach taken at Microsoft research is through deductive synthesis: https://microsoft.github.io/prose/

Comment: Another one is based more on Inductive Logic Programming. I haven't read this paper yet but since it's written by Stephen Muggleton, I assume it'll be good: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6a66/9636e0ada62a0fb444e95435e24fdbdf4dbd.pdf

Comment: I can't seem to edit my earlier comment. Since you know Neural nets, Here's a paper which uses RNN to guide the search ( program tree generation ) in Prose: https://openreview.net/forum?id=rywDjg-RW
This does compare the approach to a couple of statistical methods as well.

( I personally share the sentiment of the  "Although the search method chosen was reasonable, the only real innovation here is to use the LSTM to learn a search heuristic." review on this one, but it's good food for thought. can probably used in the other direction to use a grammar to constrain an NN

Comment: Better link to MSR's PROSE: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/programming-examples-pl-meets-ml/